# BEKK - GARCH model in Stata

Tags: volatility, garch

Is it possible to run BEKK-GARCH in Stata? mgarch is of a different model type and google provide me with no good hints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is posible to fit a BEKK in Stata, i'm not sure if you are familiar with R but with the package `MTS` you can fit a BEKK(1,1), it takes some time to run, i would suggest that you consider a CC-GARCH wich can be estimated in Stata and in R with `ccgarch` or a DCC that is also posible in both programs

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to me to use a BEKK if you were only looking at one time series. From my understanding you would use BEKK's for Multivariate (G)ARCH models. In this case you can use `mgarch dvech` or `mgarch dcc`. `dcc` stands for dynamic conditional correlation. Both of these modeling methods allow for changing conditional correlations.

see `help mgarch`